# Using R to recode several variable at once

Tags: r

My data set is like the following:

```
Q_B      Q1      Q2      Q3       Q4
1         5       4       5       3
2  
1         3       4       3       1
2                                  
1         1       1       1       1
```

What I'm doing is to change Q1 to Q4 to 0 if Q_B==2,
I use `Q1[Q_B==2]<-0,Q2[Q_B==2]<0`

I have to write the same code for Q1 to Q4, is there a easy way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

We can just do

```
df1[df1$Q_B==2,-1] <- 0
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Q_B = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Q1 = c(5L, NA, 3L, 
NA, 1L), Q2 = c(4L, NA, 4L, NA, 1L), Q3 = c(5L, NA, 3L, NA, 1L
), Q4 = c(3L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L)), .Names = c("Q_B", "Q1", "Q2", 
"Q3", "Q4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. if the data set is more complete, can we still do that. For example, if I have 10 variables in a data frame (df1) : Q_B1,Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q_B2,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8. if Q_B1==2, then Q1 to Q4 equal to 0, if Q_B2==2 then Q5 to Q8 equal to 0. I try to use        df1[,2:4][df1$Q_B1==2] and df2[,7:10][df1$Q_B2==2] but failed.

Comment: @XueyiPan It should work.  Check if the column class are `factors`

Comment: Thanks! I figured it out. the code should be `df1[df1$Q_B2==2,7:10]=0`